# Por que si estoy mandando un FormData en un servicio el que lo recibe(Back)lo interpreta como "application/json"?

Tags: python, angular, django, typescript

Buen dia
Estoy tratando de enviar claramente un FormData pero al llegar a mi back este lo lee como "application/json" pero si hago el mismo ejercicio mandando un FormData desde Postman a mi back aca si llega que es FormData

Servicio de mi Front Angular

```
createTikeckt(json:any, file:File){
console.log(file);
console.log(json);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', file, file.name);
formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(json))
// let headers = new HttpHeaders();
// headers = headers.set( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data") // estaba probando con estos headers pero tampoco funciono
return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/soporte/crear/ticket/`, formData, {
  headers: { 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest' }
});

 }
```

Este es mi urls.py en mi back

```
from django.urls import path
from soporte import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('crear/ticket/', (views.CreateTicketView.as_view()))
]
```

Este es mi views.py en mi back

```
class CreateTicketView(generics.ListAPIView):
#parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        print("hola")
        id_u = request.data['id']
        newticket = Ticket.objects.create(id_usuario=Usuario.objects.get(id=id_u), pregunta=request.data['pregunta'],
                                          detalles=request.data['detalles'], evidencia=request.FILES['evidencia'], estado_pregunta=Ticket.ENVIADA)
        newticket.save()
        if newticket.pk:
            return HttpResponse ({"Tiket entregado con exito"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return HttpResponse({"Hubo un error al entregar el tiket"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return HttpResponse({"Hubo un error al crear el ticket, intente después"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Esto es lo que me bota mi back al hacer DEBUGER pero si lo mando un FormData con Postman si me sale FormData.

Sin Postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con Postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por consecuencia a esto me llega vacio mi FromData, porfavor alguien sabe que pasa llevo mas de 1 semana taratndo de solucionar esto pero no e podido.

Ayuda porfavor.

**De ante mano muchas gracias**

**Actualizacion**

---

Quedaria algo asi?

```
return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/soporte/crear/ticket/`, formData, {headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}});
```

Como estoy realizando el envio desde Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira vi en los Headers de Postman y asi me los indica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen de Fiddler**

Abre la imagen para que la puedas leer
De mi servicio normal en angular
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es de Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Christian si vez las lineas comentadas de header? es asi o que me faltaria o como es que me dices que las especifiques

Answer (score 1):

Solo necesita agregar los encabezados correctos a su solicitud:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://192.168.1.69:8080/api/files',
  data: formData,
  header: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
    })
```

#### Actualización:

Si ejecuto la misma solicitud en Postman que muestra su captura de pantalla (excepto usando mi ID de hoja), con los mismos encabezados que está usando, mi solicitud se realiza correctamente. es decir, si envía el encabezado Content-Type con el valor application / json para esta solicitud, no debería recibir el mensaje de error que está informando (1124 - encabezado de tipo de contenido no válido).

Sin embargo, recibirá ese mensaje de error si no incluye el encabezado Content-Type en absoluto O si especifica un valor no válido para el encabezado Content-Type . Una sugerencia para la resolución de problemas: use Fiddler (o una herramienta similar) para examinar la solicitud que se envía por cable cuando ejecuta esta solicitud en Postman: ¿incluye el encabezado Content-Type y, de ser así, cuál es el valor de eso? ¿encabezamiento?

Gracias por agregar una captura de pantalla del cuerpo que está configurando en Postman; creo que esa es la fuente de su problema. es decir, su encabezado Content-Type dice que el cuerpo de la solicitud está en formato JSON, pero en realidad no está enviando JSON. Para solucionar esto: en lugar de especificar pares clave / valor en Postman, seleccione el botón de radio sin formato y especifique el cuerpo en formato JSON.

Comment: Voy a intentar ya vuelvo.

Comment: Mira arriba la pregunta que aca no puedo agregar bien el codigo return

Comment: Parece ser que siempre me esta enviando aplication/json de mi servicio asi le aplique un multipart/form-data que sera esta muy raro esto

Comment: Mira como estoy relizando mi headers para luego enviarlo al return `let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set( 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')`

Comment: Por otra parte no te entendi muy bien lo ultimo que me dijiste